# Confused about JavaScript variable persistence with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm thoroughly confused with the behavior of my JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click','.button1', function(){
  counter = 0;
});
$(document).on('click','.button2', function(){
  counter = 1;
});
$(document).on('click','.button3', function(){
  $('#score').append(counter);
});
$(document).on('click','.button4', function(){
  counter++;
  $('#score').append(counter);
});
```

If clicking button2 then button4 you would expect 2 to be appended to score. However, this only works on a full page refresh - if I re-navigate to the page (through my header bar) and press the same combination it appends 5, then 10, then 17, then 26. I don't understand why that is the case. Surely the onclick action from button2 should reassign counter to 1, but somehow counter is persisting.

I think i'm fundamentally misunderstanding how JavaScript works and would greatly any appreciate and tips or guidance here.

Thanks.

Comment: your counter only exist on your function and is deleted when the function ends. Add `var counter=0;` before your functions.

Comment: How and where is your variable "counter" being declared?

Comment: Declaring var counter fixed it. Thanks!. Haha. I'm so foolish.